# On Android how do I make oddly shaped clipping areas?

Tags: android, android-canvas, dalvik, masking

Here is how to create a clipping area the shape of a circle:

```
Path path = new Path();
path.addCircle(200,200,100,Direction.CW);
c.clipPath(path); // c is a Canvas
```

Now there's a clipping area on the Canvas which prevents drawing anything outside the bounds of that circle. But, what if I want to have the clipping area be shaped like a donut (or whatever)?

I tried playing around with creating a second Path and using toggleInverseFillType on it and then adding that to the original path, but that doesn't seem to work.

Alternatively, instead of using a Path, is it possible to just create a Bitmap to use as a mask and set it as a clipping mask on the Canvas somehow?

EDIT: The answer is exactly what I needed with one small addition. When doing multiple operations on a canvas, always use Op.REPLACE on the first clipPath call. That will replace any existing clipPath on that Canvas.

For reference, here is what I discovered what the 6 different Region.Op values mean. Imagine a venn diagram with 2 circles. "B" is  the part where the 2 circles overlap. "A" is the non-overlapping left circle. "C" is the non-overlapping right circle.

```
c.clipPath(a,Region.Op.REPLACE);
c.clipPath(b,???);

Region.Op.DIFFERENCE         -> A..            
Region.Op.INTERSECT          -> .B.            
Region.Op.REPLACE            -> .BC            
Region.Op.REVERSE_DIFFERENCE -> ..C            
Region.Op.UNION              -> ABC
Region.Op.XOR                -> A.C
```

The "." indicates the part that isn't drawn. Sorry if that's not particularly clear. It's hard to describe well without graphics.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the `Canvas` [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html):

`Canvas#clipPath(Path path, Region.Op op)` - Modify the current clip with the specified path.

So, for your donut example:

1. Create 2 Paths. One for the larger circle, one for the smaller circle.
2. `Canvas#clipPath( Path )` with larger circle `Path`.
3. Call the `Canvas#clipPath( Path, Region.Op )` method on your canvas with the smaller circle `Path` for the first argument and the appropriate [`Region.Op`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Region.Op.html) enum value for the second argument.

   ```
   Path largePath = new Path();
   largePath.addCircle(200,200,100,Direction.CW);
   Path smallPath = new Path();
   smallPath.addCircle(200,200,40,Direction.CW);
   c.clipPath(largePath); // c is a Canvas
   c.clipPath(smallPath, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
   ```

Again, modify the `Region.Op` enum value to get different effects...

Comment: clipPath not supported on Android 4

Comment: Clippath is supported just fine, if you disable Hardware Acceleration for your view/activity/application. The difference with Android 4+ is that HA is enabled by default.

Comment: clipPath is now also HA in 4.3+

Comment: Nice, `// c is Canvas` then why isn't it `canvas` instead? why be lazy when Androdi studio almost predicts what you want to type?

Comment: It literally matters none percent what the variable name for canvas is haha

Comment: Androdi is Android isn't it, so why be lazy when Chrome suggests correct spelling? :-)

Comment: @MKer How do you know he/she/it uses Chrome? Notice I didn't make any gender assumptions too!