# All of my content inside an backgroundImage

Tags: android, android-layout, background-image, android-imageview

Basically What I'd like to try is to have all of my content in an image. I looked up some stuff but what they do is always use an imageView and text. But I'd like to use it as a background image.

Can someone give me an example how this exactly works? And how will the support be for using this with different screensizes, because the content always has to stay in the image?
To clarify what I want, I added an image. The green space is a background drawn in android xml, the white is the actually image and the text should be all of my content. I'd like to keep everything in the white, even if I get more edges.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way will be to have 3 layers

Top
Mask
Content
Image
Bottom

The mask will be an imageview (in your case only the green parts with the rest transparent). 
The base image can be anything, but it would make sense that it complements the masking layer.

The content will be the tricky part. You will need to figure out the bounds of the masking layer so you won't go under the mask. I would suggest centering the content.

Alternatively, if the shape will change in size or is complex I would suggest using a canvas with a clipping pattern. [On Android how do I make oddly shaped clipping areas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285450/on-android-how-do-i-make-oddly-shaped-clipping-areas)

Comment: 3 layers, do you mean in a layer-list? I'll check out how to do a mask in android. I'll try it this evening and I'll get back to you!

Comment: For the first suggestion, I just meant three different layouts in another layout (ex all three in a relativelayout).

Comment: Fixed this with following code 
`<ImageView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
     android:paddingTop="0dp"
     android:src="@drawable/top_container"
     android:background="@drawable/bg" 
    />
 
 <ImageView 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
     android:src="@drawable/logo_prayer"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:id="@+id/logo"/>`